# Reliable click function in capybara with selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara

Sometimes the .click capybara function doesn't fire and it doesn't fail either because it assumes that it fired. So I looked around and found that .trigger("click") is more reliable with some drawbacks too.

[But I read the github for the trigger() function and it says it doesn't work in selenium.](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3fdeb0e00a46fdd50d95012b37dbf23da8b70072/lib/capybara/node/element.rb)

Is there an alternative function for a reliable click with capybara/ruby in selenium?

ex:

```
find(el).click
```

vs

```
find(el).trigger("click")
```

Comment: How do you know that the `click` event is not fired? From my experience, it's either because the listener is not yet assigned, or the event is emitted on an element just before being replaced with a new one, usually due to an asynchronous update. So the reliability mainly depend on whether the test is performing the click on an expected state or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no alternative click function in Capybara with selenium (other than potentially executing JS via `execute_script`). It's not likely the click isn't firing, it's more likely that it is firing at the "wrong" location due to animation on the page causing the calculated location of the click to be out of date by the time the click actually occurs. In that case disabling animation during testing can often help. If it isn't a wrong location issue, and you can create an example that exhibits the behavior, report it to either geckodriver or chromedriver and they will usually fix it pretty quickly (as long as you provide an example that replicates it).

Comment: @FlorentB.  With which driver/browser combo?

Comment: @FlorentB. Because with selenium/geckodriver/FF marionette the position of the element is calculated and then a mouse click event is added to the event queue on the window at the position the element was calculated to be. It then gets processed by the browsers normal processing to determine which element receives it - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/marionette/interaction.js#200 - after it waits for all other events in the queue to be processed (animation, etc) - so I don't believe your statement is correct for that combo

Comment: You are right, I checked and all the events are fired on the top element at the center location for both chrome and firefox. I don't know where I got that assumption wrong since even the former atom script is implemented the same way. I ran some tests on both firefox and chrome and even though all the event are fired on a single tick, chrome is affected by the CSS transition and either fail by throwing `element not clickable` or by firering the event on the wrong element.

Comment: On the other hand firefox always fires the events on the top element at the center location which is a surprise for once. The difference is probably because the click is fully executed by marionette withing firefox while the chomedriver needs 1 remote call through the devtool api to compute the location and another one to fire the events.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes, the element you are trying to click is hidden or overlapped, in those cases you have to use-

`find(el).trigger("click", visible: false)`

Hope that helps.

Comment: As the OP mentioned -- there is no `trigger` method when using Selenium as the driver

Comment: I would use this if it was available. Thank you though

Comment: My bad. I thought the the other way.